# How to use Jetbrains Webstorm with Citrix

Tags: webstorm, citrix

I cannot use Webstorm on my Citrix account because the screen isn't rendered properly. It is not easy to describe, it looks like a screen refresh would help. When I scroll through the source, the lines appear one by one, but some regions of the gui (icon, menues,...) are never shown.

[image: screenshot]

Comment: Do you have a screenshot demonstrating your issue? (If you are looking for a good screenshot tool, try [Jing](http://www.techsmith.com/jing.html).)

Comment: added a screenshot, you see the white regions

Answer (score 0):

Not likely the answer you would expect, but I can only suggest installing WebStorm on a local machine and working with source files located on local drives. All IDE functionality is based on the index of the project files which WebStorm builds when the project is loaded and updates on the fly as you edit your code. To provide efficient coding assistance, WebStorm needs to re-index code fast, which requires fast access to project files. The latter can be ensured only for local files, that is, files that are stored on you hard disk and are accessible through the file system.
Moreover, the fsnotifier tool IDE uses to synchronize its virtual file system with external changes doesn't support remote drives, so you might have problems synchronizing files generated by LESS/SASS compilers and other external tools...

See also https://community.oracle.com/thread/1353486